# Странности limit mysql

Tags: php, mysql

При выполнении запроса

```
<?php
require_once "conf.php";
dbConnect();
$zapros1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
$rez=mysql_fetch_array($zapros1);
while ($rez=mysql_fetch_array($zapros1)){
echo ($rez['id']);
}
```

?>

Возвращает почему-то четыре элемента, а не 5. Как быть?

Comment: А в базе самой случайно не 4 новости?

Comment: такое чувство что у тебя в базе последняя ячейка просто пустая но в ней записана эта пустота!!! проверь базу!!!

Comment: Там банальная невнимательность.. что-то из перечисленного ниже явно.

Comment: А LIMIT 6 и LIMIT 3 что выводят ?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так

```
<?php
require_once "conf.php";
dbConnect();
$zapros1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5");
while ($rez=mysql_fetch_assoc($zapros1)){
echo ($rez['id']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Правильно) @new_russian_man , вы первую запись читаете, а потом цикл запускаете)) Первая просто не выводится.

Comment: И как быть тогда?

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте `LIMIT 0,5` 
 добавлено --сравни LIMIT 0,5 и LIMIT 1,5 если первый выдает 4 новости а второй 5 новостей значит смотрим базу и удаляем последнюю строку - она пуста

Comment: Нет. Результат тот же......

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once "conf.php";
dbConnect();
$zapros1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
$rez=mysql_fetch_array($zapros1);  // sdesi vibiraetsea pervaia stroca
while ($rez=mysql_fetch_array($zapros1)){ // v tsikle vivodeatsea ostavshiesea 4..
echo ($rez['id']);
}
?>
```

Просто удалите из кода строчку

```
$rez=mysql_fetch_array($zapros1);
```

Answer (score 0):

вполне возможно что в базе недостаточно записей.

Comment: говорит что вроде как 20 записей там есть.